# No funcionan abreviaciones de emmet

Tags: visual-studio, emmet

Soy nuevo en esto, así que lamento si mi pregunta resulta un poco ridícula.

Desde hace poco funciones como la de ! para expandir el html automáticamente o multiplicar una lista con li*4 no funcionan en visual studio, ¿podríais decirme qué ha podido ser? Por si he tocado algo que no era.

Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: ¿Probaste hacerlo en un archivo con la extensión `.html`?

Comment: Sí, o sea antes creaba el archivo . html y ya podía utilizar esos shortcuts, pero ahora con el archivo creado si pongo ! no me sale la opción de autocompletar la plantilla entera de html, al igual que otras abreviaturas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontre una solucion, entra en
1-archivo/preferencias/configuracion
2-Entra en las seccion de emmet y busca donde dice Trigger Expansion On Tab
3-Habilita esa opcion, una vez habilitada podes escribir tu abreviatura por ejemplo (a*3) y al pulsar TAB va a funcionar

Comment: Arreglado, mil gracias!